# Heroku json gem install fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems

I could not push my app to heroku and when I run I get the following error

```
   An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
   Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I could not manually install the gem either because when I do

```
gem install json -v '1.8.3'

Fetching: json-1.8.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /var/lib/gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

and I cannot access sudo on `Heroku`

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the Gemlock file and try again...!

Or remove it completely so it can install all the gems from scratch